# Correct syntax to "fit" a classifier in sklearn?

Tags: scikit-learn, model

I am trying following simple example:

```
from sklearn import datasets, svm
iris = datasets.load_iris()
clf = svm.SVC(random_state=0)
```

For fitting, should I use following statement:

```
clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
```

Or just:

```
clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
```

Both above formats have been used in different places, so I am confused.

The first method `clf = clf(X,y).fit()` seems to be the official version (see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html)).

I have tried and found that both seem to work, but I may be missing some point here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both perform the same. The `fit()` function modifies the states of the estimator and returns it. It is used so that you can write a one-liner such as:

```
clf = svm.SVC(random_state=0).fit(iris.data, iris.target)
```